# Triggers Error: Compile Error: expecting a colon, found 'com.opportunity__c' at line 6 column 82

Tags: trigger

error: Compile Error: **expecting a colon**, found `com.opportunity__c` at line 6 column 82

```
trigger countCompetitor on Competitor__c (after insert, after update) {
   //select id from opportunity where name = 'opp4'
   list<opportunity> opp= new list<opportunity>();
   for (competitor__c com : Trigger.new)
   {
       integer i = [select count(id) from competitor__c where opportunities.name = com.opportunity__c];
   }
}
```

Comment: The fix for that syntax error is to add a colon `... = :com.opportunity__c`.

Comment: Apart from the error,**query** inside a **for loop** should be avoided.Use `Set` to collect the `opportunity ids` using for loop and finally use it in your query.

Answer (score 4):

Your code should be:

```
trigger countCompetitor on Competitor__c (after insert, after update) {
  //select id from opportunity where name = 'opp4'
  list<opportunity> opp= new list<opportunity>();
  for (competitor__c com : Trigger.new)
  {
    integer i = [select count(id) from competitor__c where opportunities.name = :com.opportunity__c];
  }
}
```

Do not forget the colon to bind variables, so your query needs to have this part:

```
:com.opportunity__c
```

But... making a query inside the loop will work for few records but will throw Governor Limits (too many SOQL queries) when you load data. So the code should look like this:

```
trigger countCompetitor on Competitor__c (after insert, after update) {
    Set<Id> ids = new Set<ID>();
    for (competitor__c com : Trigger.new) {
        ids.add(com.opportunity__c);
    }
    System.debug([SELECT opportunity__c, count(id) FROM competitor__c GROUP BY opportunity__c WHERE opportunity__c in :ids]);

}
```

Finally, note that I have changed the search from Name to IDs, because it's a bit more efficient to search on IDs than on Strings ;-)